# Launcher has leaked IntentReceiver - not using BroadcastReceiver at all

Tags: android

I just started out with Android development so I'm by far no expert. Today I noticed a weird LogCat error. I have no idea when I introduced it into my app and no clue how to fix this.

It seems that it has something to do with registering/unregistering BroadcastReceiver.

My problem ist - I don't use this concept anywhere (did not even look into it). I removed all code from my project except one completely empty Activity.

Still - when I launch my project on my device, the error pops up:

```
11-06 19:02:13.691 4039-4039/? E/ActivityThread: Activity com.android.launcher2.Launcher has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.launcher2.Launcher$3@52bf5b4 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                                                 android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.android.launcher2.Launcher has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.launcher2.Launcher$3@52bf5b4 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1222)
                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:993)
                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1348)
                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1328)
                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1322)
                                                     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:630)
                                                     at com.android.launcher2.Launcher.onResume(Launcher.java:1081)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1277)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7101)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3821)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3885)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3051)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

What could possibly be the cause of it?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else comes across this issue...

It occured after I upgraded (the project) to Android Studio 3.0.
I don't really know what the problem was but in my last desperate attempt I just created a NEW project and copied all the sources and resources over.

Low and behold! The error is gone.